# Interrupting a For Loop for entering the user input in each cycle of loop

Tags: vba, for-loop

I am using a For loop to flash two criterias on a form. Next to them is a TextBox for entering the score by the user based on those criterias. I am trying that a user input is entered every time loop completes a cycle. Dont wan't to use the InputBox interrupt. The problem is the after first score the loop keep flashing the MsgBox and doesn't allow user to update the score TextBox. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Cb_Submit_Click()
Debug.Print (No_of_Comparisons)
Debug.Print (Criterias_No)
For i = 1 To Criterias_No
    For j = 3 To Criterias_No
        If j <= Criterias_No And i < j Then
            Lab_Criteria1.Caption = Worksheets("PairWiseMatrix").Range("A" & i + 3).Value
            Lab_Criteria2.Caption = Worksheets("PairWiseMatrix").Range("A" & j + 3).Value
            MsgBox "You have entered a Comparative Score of " & Tb_Score.Value, vbOKOnly
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: So you want it to prompt before/after each `j` loop?

Comment: After every j loop

Comment: then move the `MsgBox` line to after the `Next j` line.